# Adding elements to vector with initial element as maximum

Tags: r, vector

I have this vector in R:

```
x<-c(2, 4, 6,5)
```

I would like to create a bigger vector which has the numbered list of numbers from 1 up until each element in `x`.This is what I need:

```
xyz<-c(1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5)
```

I am not sure how to go about doing this. I can print them out by

```
for (i in 1:4) print (1:x[i])
```

but when I try to make them into a vector by

```
for (i in 1:4) xyz<-c((1:x[i]))
```

doesn't seem to work. Can somebody help please?

Comment: `sequence( x )` gives `[1] 1 2 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5`. This is a duplicate of a question a few days ago...

Comment: My bad, I did not find this in my search. Thanks so much for helping out.

Comment: No worries - there are not really any keywords you could have used to find it I guess.